# Payara Micro: turn off X-Frame-Options header

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, iframe, x-frame-options, payara-micro

we are starting mini project based on Payara micro 5.183. The project will always be incorporated in other websites using an iframe. However, default behaviour which we are encountering is that all http responses have header set as:

`X-Frame-Options: sameorigin`

I was trying to use `asadmin` commands, but they do not seem to be working yet...

Is there simple way to change this default behaviour without writing custom filters?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this works in 5.x or micro profile but this is how we do it in 4.x.
From the command line like this

```
asadmin set configs.config.server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-1.http.xframe-options=false
```

you'll have to change the specified listeners to match your configuration.

You can also do it from the admin UI under server-config->Network Config->Protocols->Listener
[image]